# Simple counting program issue

Tags: c

For some reason, my printf and scanf are undeclared apparently. I think it's something to do with my functions which I don't understand very well.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

void testCount ();

int eleven = 11;
int input = 0;
int output = 0;
int count = 0;

int main (){
    printf("What number would you like to count to?");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    testCount();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void testCount (int x){
    int y;
    for(y=1;y<count;y++){
        if (x < 10){ 
           x + 1;
        }
    }    
    output = input/eleven;
}
```

Comment: The prototype and function signature of `testCount` differs, change to `void testCount(int);`, also, you forget to pass `count` in `testCount();`

Comment: Strangest program ever!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `#include <stdio.h>` to fix the problem with `printf()` and `scanf()`. You have `#include <stdlib.h>` twice.

Also, you should change:

```
void testCount ();
```

to:

```
void testCount (int x);
```

as suggested by @ Keine Lust. And please don't forget to pass a value to your newly minted `testCount()` function!

Comment: Okay, sorry was a rather stupid mistake. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sometimes it takes another set of eyeballs to see the simplest things :)

Comment: btw, there is nothing in the code that you showed us that requires `ctype.h`, so you should remove that from your `#include`s, unless you have plans to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of Errors in program.

1. You declared `<stdlib.h>` twice.
2. You are not printing anything to get output.
3. Either testcount() should print Output or return it to main().
4. testcount() should take count as an argumnet.

   Make the following changes:

   ```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>       //declaration of stdio lib
   #include <ctype.h>

    void testCount (int);  // declaration of datatype of parameter

    int eleven = 11;
    int input = 0;
    int output = 0;
    int count = 0;

    int main ()
     {
   printf("What number would you like to count to?");
   scanf("%d", &count);
   testCount(count);         // pass value of count so function testcount() can copy that value to variable x 
   system("pause");        // no need of this line
   return 0;
    }

     void testCount (int x)
     {
      int y;
       for(y=1;y<count;y++)
        {


   if (x < 10)
     { 
        x + 1;
      }
       }    
      output = input/eleven;

      printf("Output is :%d",output);
      }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much, think I fixed it now.